# How to set session attribute on login?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring security, can some values be stored in session when login is success? Which class should be overide?

```
"AuthenticationSuccessHandler" is used for this case? How should I use it?
```

Below is the configuration of spring security.

```
        <b:bean id="myFilter"
            class="net.ebaolife.tpa.security.MyFilterSecurityInterceptor">
            <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
            <b:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="myAccessDecisionManagerBean">
            </b:property>
            <b:property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="securityMetadataSource">
            </b:property>
        </b:bean>

        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailService">
                <!-- <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" /> -->
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

        <b:bean id="myUserDetailService" class="net.ebaolife.tpa.security.MyUserDetailService" />

        <b:bean id="myAccessDecisionManagerBean" class="net.ebaolife.tpa.security.MyAccessDecisionManager" />

        <b:bean id="securityMetadataSource" class="net.ebaolife.tpa.security.MyInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" />
```

Comment: What is it you want to do that you cannot do right now? Just implement your own `PasswordEncoder`. Also validation and storing things in the session are different responsibilities and don't belong in the same class imho.

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to do two things. 1. Compare password between one from backend and one from front end. Is "PasswordEncoder" only used to encrypt password from front end? Then how should I change the way to compare two data. In my case, I may want to add some prefix to password from user imput. 2. Once validation is done or user is logged in, where should I set some session attribute?

Comment: Spring security already does or can do all that, so why reinvent the wheel? Passwords should be stored encrypted, the password encoder is hence only used to encode the input before the comparison, for adding a prefix that is what a so called `salt` is used for, which Spring Security also supports.

Comment: yeah, you are right. It's not a good example. Maybe I need to add one “verification code”, pass it to back end to do further validation.  I know "UserDetailService" is used to fetch the user detail and authentication info,   just don't know how spring security validate password and whether it can be customized.

Comment: Add a `AuthenticationProvider` for that which operates on a custom `Authentication` which would include the `username`, `password` and your additional `token`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I can get all I want in "MyDaoAuthenticationProvider", it fix my problem.